# Unable to remove item in session jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have set a list of items into the session using this piece of code

```
session.setAttribute("selectedList",listSelected);
```

Later, I wanted to remove that `selectedList` attribute from the session on clicked event of a button, like so

```
<button type="reset" style="text-align: center" onclick="function openPage(pageUrl) {
                        sessionStorage.removeItem('selectedList');
                        window.localStorage.removeItem('selectedList');
                        window.location.href = pageUrl;
                    }
                    openPage('/TN2_war_exploded/SupplierPage/SupplierSearch.jsp')">Cancel
        </button>
```

Despite trying both methods, `sessionStorage.removeItem` and `window.localStorage.removeItem`, when I move back to the page, the session still holds my list and informations within are still displayed

What did I do wrong? any tip is appreciated

Comment: Don't mix and match server side sessions with client side sessionStorage. These are totally different things.

Comment: @vanje I see, thanks, is there anyway to trigger the server session remove method on button Cancel click event? other than making a servlet?

Comment: No you have to make a request to the server and inside your servlet you can access the session attributes.